# hyperref causes problem with doc.sty

Tags: hyperref, package-writing, documentation

Try the following code. Without `hyperref` everything is fine and there’s the right entry in the index. With `hyperref` this entry disappears. (The codeline entries which are not shown here ar not touched by using `hyperref`)

```
\documentclass{ltxdoc}

%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{doc}

\EnableCrossrefs
\CodelineIndex

\begin{document}
Test\DescribeMacro{\name}

\PrintIndex
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to use both packages?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [`hypdoc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hypdoc) package is available specifically to augment `doc` with [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) abilities. Thus you should simply use

```
\usepackage{hypdoc}
```

in place of

```
\usepackage{doc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

This adds a few additional bells-and-whistles to the overall set up, so it's better than interfacing the two packages yourself.

Comment: Oh, nice. I didn't know there's such a package.

Comment: Thanks, but that does’t solve the problem completely. I had to add `\hyperpage{#1}`to the `\usage` macro to get links for index entries of `\DescribeMacro`/`\DescribeEnv`. Could this be a bug?

Answer (score 9):

The [MakeIndex](http://ctan.org/pkg/makeindex) program, which is used to process the `.ind` file, expects index entries of form

```
\index{<item>|<cmd>}
```

which means to format the page number of item with `\<cmd>`.

If you look at the `.ind` file generated with `hyperref`, you will see that the index entry command really is

```
\indexentry{name=\verb!*+\name+|usage|hyperpage}{1}
```

That is, there are *two* formatting commands `\usage` and `\hyperpage` — one from `doc` and one from `hyperref`! This confuses MakeIndex and it doesn't produce output. The solution is to redefine `\usage` to include `\hyperpage` in it, and tell `hyperref` not to override index commands:

```
\documentclass{ltxdoc}

\usepackage[hyperindex=false]{hyperref}

\EnableCrossrefs
\CodelineIndex

\let\oldusage=\usage
\renewcommand{\usage}[1]{\oldusage{\hyperpage{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\DescribeMacro{\name}
Test

\PrintIndex

\end{document}
```

You might also want to add hyperlinks to the page numbers of change history in a similar way:

```
\let\oldglossary=\glossary
\renewcommand{\glossary}[1]{\oldglossary{#1|hyperpage}}
```

Comment: Thanks Andrey. I used Josephs answer but your answer about `\hyperpage` helped too :-)